# How to retrive values from JSON returned by php

Tags: javascript, php, json

Following are my code i want to retrieve values from JSON which is returned by php file.
following are my php code.

```
$i=1;
foreach($chck as $value){
$qry_a = "SELECT ans_tags FROM wp_pp_actionphp_answers where id=".$value['answer_id'];
$result_a = $wpdb->get_results( $qry_a );  
$final[]=array(
       "question_id_$i"=>$value['question_id'],
       "answer_id_$i"=>$value['answer_id'],
       "ans_tags_$i"=>$result_a[0]->ans_tags,
       "test_attempt_$i"=>$test_count_by_email,
       );
       $i++;
   }
$jsonstring = json_encode($final);
print_r($jsonstring);//Return JSON to javascript file
exit();
```

Following are my javascript code.

```
function get_result(result_id,email){
var data='result_id=' + result_id+"&email="+email;
            $.post(
            ajaxurl + '?action=actionphp_get_result',
            data,
            function(result){
                document.write(result);

            }
            );
```

}

following are my result.

```
[{"question_id_1":"2","answer_id_1":"3","ans_tags_1":"","test_attempt_1":"181"},{"question_id_2":"1","answer_id_2":"1","ans_tags_2":"This is a tag test","test_attempt_2":"181"}]
```

How can i retrive values.

Comment: You should probably search for this first (before posting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply parse the JSON in Javascript:

```
var data = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2, \"c\": [1,2,3]}"; // your result
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you can simply access the data stored in `obj`:

```
obj.a -> 1
obj.b -> 2
obj.c[0] -> 1
```

EDIT (thanks to Webomatik):

Of course you have to have to pay attention to your result. In your case your result is an array, so you could access the single objects in the array via

```
obj[0].question_id_1 // "2"
obj[0].answer_id_1 // "3"
```

Comment: Good answer. I woud just point out that result is an array of objects, so the correct access to the values would be obj[0].question_id_1, obj[0].answer_id_1, etc.....

Comment: Yeah, but that depends on his result, but you are right, in his use scenario it would be an array.

Comment: Thanks @LucaSchimweg for your help. I am stuck into weird situation the code runs all good at localhost but as i deployed on server the array returns 0. 
updated php code:
$final[]=array("test_attempt"=>$test_count_by_email);

I have changed the js per your suggestion:
function(result){
     alert(result);
     var i=1,total=0;
     var obj = JSON.parse(result);
     var array_size=Object.keys(obj).length;
alert(obj[i].question_id);
}

Could you please help me out.

Comment: Doesn't help much if you tell it like that, best would be if you open a new question and tell us about your versions, if the PHP runs on the same host the website is on, ...

Comment: Live sever version PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
localhost PHP Version 7.0.5

Since i am a new user am having limited access to post questions,request to please be with me on comment over this question.

Comment: @LucaSchimweg waiting for your response, would be great if you can help me out. 
Thanks

Comment: have you updated the url? You can't request to http://localhost if you deployed the script

Comment: I am sorry, not able to understand what you mean by updating the url?

Comment: to what URL do you make the HTTP-Request in the Javascript?

Comment: I have used $.post(
    ajaxurl + '?action=actionphp_get_result',
    data,
    function(result){
}
and as suggested by you, I have changed the post URL and deployed on server, still it shows 0 while fetching array on server.

Comment: how is ajaxurl defined?

Comment: 'ajaxurl' is path of the start file in wordpress. The code on start.php is:
add_action( 'wp_ajax_actionphp_get_result', array($router, 'get_result'));
and get_result() is a function which is calling perfectly by add_action.

Comment: Then i've got no idea

Comment: Thanks @LucaSchimweg for your quick support.